# Are ceramic plates generally oven-safe?

Tags: equipment

Can you cook food in a ceramic eating plate in the oven at 300 degrees Fahrenheit?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but make sure it's actually ceramic if you intend to roast for a long time. Some plates are a slightly cheaper (but still kiln-fired) clay dipped in glaze, and could be prone to cracking from thermal expansion and contraction.

But at just 300 degrees for an hour or less, I don't think it would be a problem either way.

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to
[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceramic)

> Ceramics generally can withstand very high temperatures, such as
>   temperatures that range from 1,000 °C to 1,600 °C (1,800 °F to 3,000
>   °F).